# Wordpress Pagination on custom Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some code below, and the pagination seems to be failing after the second page. I'm sure that I've done something wrong on one of the loops.

Can someone sanity check my code below for me?

```
<?php get_header();?>
<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="container fullwidth">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active" style="background:url(<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/uploads/2018/09/testphoto.jpg);">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="carousel-caption microstory">
            <h1>Backstage Blog</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->

    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Carousel -->

<!-- Posts -->
<div class="container paddingtop paddingbottom">
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// are we on page one?
if(1 == $paged) { ?>
            <div class="row row-eq-height paddingbottom">
                <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&order=DESC&orderby=date&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) :?>   
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 postpaddingbottom">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="featuredimage"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></a></div>
                         <div class="blog-column">
                         <div class="titledatemain">
                            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                             <ul class="blog-detail"> 
                                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></li> 
                            </ul> 
                            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                         </div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="buttonblack">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile;?> 
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $query2 = new WP_Query( 'post_type=advert&order=DESC&orderby=date&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $query2->have_posts() ) :?>  
                <?php while ( $query2->have_posts() ) : $query2->the_post(); 
            $advert_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true); 
            $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); ?>
                    <div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 postpaddingbottom">
                    <a href="<?php echo $advert_url ?>"><div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 advertbox" style="background:url(<?php echo $featured_img_url ?>);">
                    </div></a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
           </div>              


<?php  
$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&order=DESC&orderby=date&posts_per_page=3&offset=1&paged='. $paged ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) :?>              
           <div class="row row-eq-height paddingbottom">
           <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 postpaddingbottom">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="featuredimage blogimagesmall" style="background:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>);"></div></a>
                         <div class="blog-colum">
                            <div class="titledate">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                             <ul class="blog-detail"> 
                                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time( 'F jS, Y' ); ?></li> 
                            </ul> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
            </div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php } else { ?>

<?php  
$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&order=DESC&orderby=date&posts_per_page=12&offset=4&paged='. $paged ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) :?>              
           <div class="row row-eq-height paddingbottom">
           <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 postpaddingbottom">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="featuredimage blogimagesmall" style="background:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>);"></div></a>
                         <div class="blog-colum">
                            <div class="titledate">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                             <ul class="blog-detail"> 
                                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time( 'F jS, Y' ); ?></li> 
                            </ul> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </div>
<?php 
wp_reset_postdata();
endif; ?>

<?php } ?>
<div class="row paddingbottom">
<div class="pagenav">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts', $query-   >max_num_pages) ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Older Posts', $query->max_num_pages) ?></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End Posts -->

<?php get_footer();?>
```

I'm sure that there is just a mistake in my loop. I have essentially got a different layout on the first page to the rest of the pages (as you will see).

It just seems that after page 2, when you go to the 3rd page, it just keeps displaying the 2nd page content.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Whr are you writing two queries?

Comment: I agree with @Gufran Hasan ... you should attempt simplify your code down to one query ...

Comment: anyone know of a way to just offset the first post only on the first page? As I have it working ok, but I want to offset 1 post on the first page only.

Comment: I'm still see no reason (based upon your code) to justify an **if/else** resulting in two queries. The  **previous/next_posts_link()** should do all the heavy lifting for you

Comment: the if/else was just for if it was on the first page only. I've put some updated code below :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code:

```
            <?php /* Template Name: Blog Page */ ?>
            <?php get_header();?>
            <!-- Carousel -->
            <div class="container fullwidth">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <div class="item active" style="background:url(<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/uploads/2018/09/testphoto.jpg);">
                    <div class="container">
                       <div class="carousel-caption microstory">
                        <h1>Backstage Blog</h1>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </div><!-- End Item -->

                  </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Carousel -->

            <!-- Posts -->
            <div class="container paddingtop paddingbottom">
            <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            // are we on page one?

            $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&order=DESC&orderby=date&posts_per_page=12&paged='. $paged );
            if(1 == $paged) { ?>
            <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>  
                        <div class="row row-eq-height paddingbottom">
                        <?php $temp_query2 = $wp_query2; ?>
                            <?php $query3 = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&order=DESC&orderby=date&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>   
                            <?php while ( $query3->have_posts() ) : $query3->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 postpaddingbottom">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="featuredimage"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></a></div>
                                     <div class="blog-column">
                                     <div class="titledatemain">
                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                         <ul class="blog-detail"> 
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></li> 
                                        </ul> 
                                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                     </div>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="buttonblack">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php $wp_query2 = $temp_query2; ?>

                            <?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
                            <?php $query2 = new WP_Query( 'post_type=advert&order=DESC&orderby=date&posts_per_page=1' ); ?> 
                            <?php while ( $query2->have_posts() ) : $query2->the_post(); 
                            $advert_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true); 
                            $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); ?>
                                <div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 postpaddingbottom">
                                <a href="<?php echo $advert_url ?>"><div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 advertbox" style="background:url(<?php echo $featured_img_url ?>);">
                                </div></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php $wp_query = $temp_query; ?>
                       </div>
                       <div class="row row-eq-height paddingbottom">
                       <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 postpaddingbottom">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="featuredimage blogimagesmall" style="background:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>);"></div></a>
                                     <div class="blog-colum">
                                        <div class="titledate">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                                         <ul class="blog-detail"> 
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time( 'F jS, Y' ); ?></li> 
                                        </ul> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endwhile;
                            rewind_posts();
                            }?>
                        </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                       <div class="row row-eq-height paddingbottom">
                       <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 postpaddingbottom">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="featuredimage blogimagesmall" style="background:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>);"></div></a>
                                     <div class="blog-colum">
                                        <div class="titledate">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                                         <ul class="blog-detail"> 
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php the_time( 'F jS, Y' ); ?></li> 
                                        </ul> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endwhile;?>
                        </div>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="row paddingbottom">
            <div class="pagenav">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts', $query->max_num_pages) ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Older Posts', $query->max_num_pages) ?></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Posts -->

            <?php get_footer();?>
```

You should see i'm now running one loop which is nice.. but I have put the first post in its own loop within a loop to show the first post. The issue i'm having now is that I want to on the main loop and only on the first page, have an offset of 1. But I can't work out how to do this just on the first page :(